# Keyboard shortcuts not working in eclipse

Tags: windows, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

The keyboard shortcuts for eclipse IDE 2018-12 are not working on windows 10. For example, if I press the key <kbd>F2</kbd> it is supposed to focus on the function variable which the cursor is pointing to. Instead, the volume is being muted which is the original function of the key <kbd>F2</kbd> as per the OS.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If F2 mutes the volume means that the keypress is caught and does not reach the application (Eclipse). Is there another application where you can use F2 (e. g. in Windows in the _Explorer_ to rename a file)? Maybe you accidentally pressed `Fn Lock` on your keyboard.

Comment: Thank you. Its a blunder from my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the volume is muted by <kbd>F2</kbd>, that means the <kbd>F2</kbd> **keypress is caught before reaching** the focused application (in this case **Eclipse**). It should happen in other application, too (e. g. in Windows in the *Explorer* when hitting <kbd>F2</kbd> to rename a file or folder).

Maybe you accidentally pressed <kbd>Fn Lock</kbd> on your keyboard or switched to the function key assignment in some other way.